# Is it possible to find a threshold target value with a certain confidence interval for winning, based on the given data?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

In case of a cricket match, there are two teams. One gets to bat first while the other bowls and then the reverse happens. The team batting first sets a target number of runs for the following team. The team that bats second, is chasing a target number of runs, trying to make 1 more than the target to win, while the other team tries to defend its total by trying to bowl the batsmen out.

I am trying to understand, if if is possible, given data, to compute a threshold target number for both cases - Chasing and Defending which I can say (with some confidence level), that

1. Team will be able to chase and win if the Target value is between X and Y
2. Team will be able to defend and win if the Target value is between X and Y

   (with X,Y simply being the Target Interval)

I am not sure if I have sufficient data, or if I do what exact techniques will be required here.

I have the following data for the Indian Cricket team for the years 2008-10.

[image]